# Stop a SetInterval in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So I was looking out for some help since video after video of programming I still cannot find a way to stop the 'SetInterval' command whenever I want in Microsoft edge developer console. the webpage I'm trying this at is "m.facebook" in the messages tab while in a conversation. Reason is because over there I'm trying to recover a long ago conversation. This is what I have so far as javascript and any help will be more than welcome (I'm not a programmer by the way):

```
setInterval (function () {
    document.getElementById('see_older')
       .getElementsByClassName('content')[0].click();
}, 500);
```

I just want the command to stop doing the clicks on the 'see_older' element, and of course the page not to refresh, or to know another method that will click several times on the 'see_older' element and just stop when I want.

Comment: Assign the result of `setInterval` to a variable, and then pass that variable as a parameter to `clearInterval` later.

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearInterval()`:

```
var intevalId = setInterval (function () {
...

clearInterval(intevalId); /* where you want to stop */
```